# How do I structure the presentation of a custom view controller in iOS 8/Swift? Variable initialization is proving difficult

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, swift, ios8

I have a custom `UIViewController` subclass I'd like to present. A button in one view controller in my Storyboard is hooked up to present this custom view controller.

In code, I want to set a few @IBOutlet for the new view controller that is being presented. I'm used to doing this in `prepareForSegue`, grabbing the `destinationViewController` and then setting some labels and image views and whatnot.

But now in Swift and iOS 8, I keep getting that

> can't unwrap Optional.none

Which makes me think that in iOS 8 when `prepareForSegue` is called the subviews of the view controller aren't all created yet? Am I unable to mess with the outlets at this point? How am I supposed to set them? I tried having these superfluous temporary variables holding their data (which just seems like poor design and redundant), then setting the actual outlets in `viewDidLoad`, but I get the same error and my labels are `nil` in `viewDidLoad`.

How am I supposed to set these up?

Comment: Can you add the code you are using in `prepareForSegue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to use your `prepareForSegue` function:

```
if segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier" {
    let yourViewController = segue.destinationViewController as YourDestinationViewController
    yourViewController.receivedArray = listArray
}
```

If it's not sufficient, just let me know and edit your question with the code your are using right now.